# Make one form move another one at the same time (C#)

Tags: c#, forms, drag

I have a main form Form1, and a secondary one, LogForm.  When LogForm first appears, it should have its upper left corner touching Form1's upper right.  I can do that part.  However, I would also like it if I could have LogForm stay touching Form1 if I move Form1 (ie, dragging Form1 drags LogForm with it).  Any ideas how to do that?  Edit: I'm very new to mouse events, so if that's involved, please explain thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Move` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.move.aspx) to handle the position update.  The event will return the new position of the form - the top left.  Add the width of the form to this, and you should be able to gain the positional information you require.

Comment: LocationChanged is a bit more normative, but Move will work.  It does however not 'return the new position', use the Location property.

Comment: followed Kami's advice; my solution is in answer

Answer (score 2):

Final answer; works great! (lf is a LogForm)

```
private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Point f1pos = self.Location; 
    Point logPos = new Point(f1pos.X + this.Width + 5, f1pos.Y + 5); 
    lf.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual; 
    lf.DesktopLocation = logPos; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Main Window add an Eventhandler

```
 this.LocationChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.MainWindow_LocationChanged);
```

in the eventhandler routine call

```
SlaveWindow.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + this.Width, this.Location.Y);
```

from the LocationChanged Eventhandler